# Multi-indexed Pandas Dataframe division

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Consider a multi-indexed dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 3), index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 3), index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 3), index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0, keys=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Which gives `df`:

```
            col1        col2        col3
A   a   0.893752    0.554021    0.492867
    b   0.319270    0.263366    0.542281
    c   0.082265    0.635637    0.796405
B   a   0.954748    0.684624    0.488293
    b   0.485414    0.966693    0.211348
    c   0.411648    0.989666    0.028412
C   a   0.701327    0.025172    0.320882
    b   0.073527    0.060885    0.111406
    c   0.169269    0.627686    0.438393
```

(your numbers will differ)

How do I:

- divide row (A, b) and (A, c) by (A, a)
- divide row (B, b) and (B, c) by (B, a)
- divide row (C, b) and (C, c) by (C, a)

...in one call?

My attempt:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
ratio_list = [df.loc[idx[x,:], :].div(df.loc[idx[x,'a'], :]) for x in ['A', 'B', 'C']]
ratio = pd.concat(ratio_list, axis=0)
```

Which gives `ratio`:

```
            col1        col2        col3
A   a   1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
    b   0.357225    0.475371    1.100259
    c   0.092044    1.147315    1.615864
B   a   1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
    b   0.508422    1.412005    0.432830
    c   0.431159    1.445560    0.058186
C   a   1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
    b   0.104840    2.418784    0.347188
    c   0.241355    24.936324   1.366214
```

---

See below answers from @Smordy and @ouoboros1. Both are excellent. `groupby-transform` is more concise but `np.repeat` is definitely more performant when size of the dataframe is big.

```
nrow = 100  # iterate through this
df = df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(nrow*3, 3), 
                       columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
                       index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[*'ABC'], ['row' + str(ii) for ii in range(0, nrow)]]))

# pandas `groupby-transform` from @Smordy
%timeit df.div(df.groupby(level=0).transform('first'))

# `numpy.repeat` from @ouroboros1 
%timeit df.div(np.repeat(df.loc[(slice(None), ['row0']), :].to_numpy(), nrow, axis=0))
```

Results:

[image]

Here it seems time-factor plateaus around 3x. If we increase the number of columns, the time-factor will go up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

- Select all `"a"` values from index level 1 and then use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to get the result with shape `(3, 3)` into the same shape as your original `df` (i.e. `(9, 3)` using 3 repeats on `axis=0`).
- Simply pass the result to [`df.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0) # for reproducibility

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(9, 3), 
             columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[*'ABC'],[*'abc']]))

%timeit df.div(np.repeat(df.loc[(slice(None),['a']),:], 3, axis=0))
# 175 µs ± 3.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

df = df.div(np.repeat(df.loc[(slice(None),['a']),:], 3, axis=0))

df

         col1      col2      col3
A a  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
  b  0.992839  0.592367  1.071555
  c  0.797333  1.246905  1.598741
B a  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
  b  1.481437  1.169089  0.134310
  c  0.227230  0.025537  1.574263
C a  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
  b  1.026989  0.530429  0.797583
  c  0.151993  0.735531  0.146485
```

*Update*: depending on your version of `np` (< version 1.24, it seems), you need to convert the selection to a `np.ndarray` before passing it to `np.repeat`. Use [`df.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html). I.e., `df.div(np.repeat(df.loc[(slice(None),['a']),:].to_numpy(), 3, axis=0))`.

---

**Performance comparison**

Comparing with [groupby method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76722987/18470692) by [@Smordy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18392496/smordy):

```
np.random.seed(0)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(9, 3), 
             columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[*'ABC'],[*'abc']]))

%timeit df2.div(df2.groupby(level=0).transform('first'))
# 488 µs ± 73.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

df2 = df2.div(df2.groupby(level=0).transform('first'))

print(df.equals(df2))
# True
```

Factor 2.8 faster.

---

Incidentally, if you add [`names`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.names.html) to your MultiIndex, you can also use [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), like so:

```
df.index.names = ['l0','l1']

df = df.div(np.repeat(df.query("l1 == 'a'"), 3, axis=0))
```

That reads well, but would actually be slower:

```
%timeit df.div(np.repeat(df.query("l1 == 'a'"), 3, axis=0))
875 µs ± 13.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: For some reason I have to add `np.repeat(df.loc[...].values, 3, axis=0)`, otherwise numpy complains about the shape. Anyway I followed your approach and compared performance at different sizes of the matrix. Your answer should be the accepted one. I will add performance comparison in my OP.

Comment: You're right. Initially, working with np 1.24.3, it works as shown above, but in a different env with np 1.23.5, I get the same complaint. I don't see an update on `np.repeat` between the two versions though. To be safe, add `df.to_numpy` (note that `df.values` is no longer recommended). This will impact performance slightly, though scaled with more groups the difference between the two methods will be rather significant either way.

Answer (score 2):

you can try with more efficiently by using `groupby` along with `transform`

```
result = df.div(df.groupby(level=0).transform('first'))
```

Comment: Amazing. Forgot the almighty `transform`!

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to debug with random generated df, but you can try something like that:

- reset index to perform groupby
- groupby/transform to apply your groupby result to the initial df
- divide to get the ratio

```
df = df.reset_index(names=["index1", "index2"])

for col in ["col1", "col2", "col3"]:
    df[col] = df[col] / (
        df
        .groupby("index1")[col]
        .transform("first")
    )
```

```
# input df
      col1   col2   col3
A a  0.964  0.227  0.058
  b  0.409  0.331  0.279
  c  0.319  0.456  0.985
B a  0.113  0.464  0.990
  b  0.495  0.484  0.176
  c  0.299  0.911  0.481
C a  0.149  0.474  0.695
  b  0.235  0.508  0.487
  c  0.416  0.666  0.234


# output df
  index1 index2   col1   col2    col3
0      A      a  1.000  1.000   1.000
1      A      b  0.424  1.457   4.853
2      A      c  0.330  2.009  17.117
3      B      a  1.000  1.000   1.000
4      B      b  4.368  1.042   0.178
5      B      c  2.641  1.964   0.486
6      C      a  1.000  1.000   1.000
7      C      b  1.572  1.070   0.700
8      C      c  2.784  1.404   0.337
```